# Rails ChartKick blank set default label yAxis value to 0 .. 10 .. 20

Tags: ruby-on-rails, label, linechart, chartkick, yaxis

When chart is blank set yAxis labels with values 0, 10 and 20.

I use this code and not resolve.

```
<%= line_chart(
                              [
                                  { name: "Evolução da carteira", data: @account_evolution  },
                                  { name: "Novos Clientes",       data: @new_proposals }
                              ], {library: {yAxis: {ticks: (0..20).to_a}}})
                      %>
```

[image]

the chart load with 0, 0.5 and 1 labels

Answer (score 1):

This resolve:

```
library: { scales: { yAxes: [{ ticks: { min: 0, max: 20, stepSize: 10 } }]
```